# com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Getting "com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle" error after upgrading android studio to Flamingo.

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip

[image]

Comment: Any solution ? I stuck in same thing!

Comment: I faced same bug when i upgrade to gradle 8.0. When i comment to agconnect plugins its working but i need them.

Comment: Yes, correct there is some issue with HMS agconnect plugin.